# Paypal Implementation: Hidden Elements to PHP

Tags: php, security, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am implementing Paypal paying to my website. But there are some hidden form elements for example the price and these we can easily manipulate. How can I hide them perfect in PHP for example so nobody can manipulate the value?

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">

    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@email.com">

    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Item Example 1">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="5.95">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://example.com/cancel.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://example.com/success.php'>

    <input type="image" name="submit" border="0"
    src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
    <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" >

</form>
```

The hidden elements `item_name`, `item_number`, `amount` and `currency_code` i don't want see them. Is there a chance to hide them for example with PHP or somehow?

Thank you very much!

Comment: keep the info in session on your server and cancel the order if the values were changed, or sign the order with an HMAC and pass that through to paypal and check it after it goes though

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with Payments Standard and hide the details you'll need to use a hosted button.  During the process of creating a button in your PayPal account there is an option to "save button at PayPal."  This will create a hosted button, in which case all of the details are stored at PayPal, so the button code only has a button ID which means nothing to anybody trying anything tricky.

If you are building the form yourself, though, you can't do that.  You could do what @Neil McGuigan mentioned and try to cancel/refund through IPN if the data doesn't match up to what it should be, but that's not what I would recommend.

I would recommend using the [Express Checkout API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) instead of Payments Standard.  This is the most secure way to get it done, and as you grow with your site you won't be as limited as you would be with Payments Standard.

This [PayPal PHP SDK](https://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-sdk-php/) will make the Express Checkout API calls very quick and easy for you.  Specifically, you'll be working with [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/), [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/), and [DoExpressCheckoutPayment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/).

The library comes with samples and templates that are ready to go, but if you'd prefer a [fully functional demo](https://www.angelleye.com/product-category/php-class-libraries/demo-kits/) those are available, too.